# MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

I've just installed Mongo, Node, etc. and when I try to update the database via my nodejs server, I get this error:

```
MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version
```

Here are the versions I have:

- [Node](https://nodejs.org/download/) v0.12.2 (latest is v0.12.3)
- [Express](http://expressjs.com) v4.12.4 (latest is v4.12.4)
- [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) v3.0.3  (latest is v3.0.3)
- [Mongodb Node.js Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) v2.0.33 (latest is v2.0.33)
- [Mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) v1.3.23 (latest is v1.3.23)

I have the latest versions of everything, and I've searched the [node mongodb driver git](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) to find out [what version of mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) is supported but I couldn't find anything :(

I also read the other SO questions about it, and it says to update your mongodb, but mine is the latest release!

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect [the mongoskin peerDependency declaration](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/8dcf669ff808463191033cc1e3917caa2bc41984/package.json#L24) specifying `~1.4` is your issue. To confirm, directly run `npm install mongodb@latest` and write a test file that requires `mongodb` directly and connects to and queries your database. I suspect that will work fine which will confirm that the mongoskin peerDependency is the issue. You may need to file an issue with mongoskin and ask them to update to support the 2.x releases of node-mongodb-native.

Comment: So now what do we do?!?